# Autoconf and makefile

Tags: makefile, autotools, autoconf

I am trying to learn GNU autotools, and I am following some tutorials, I tried doing step by step from:

http://kern-81.homepage.t-online.de/autotools_tutorial.pdf

but I have one question, at page 8 there is manually written Makefile.in and one line:

```
BINDIR=@bindir@
```

after

```
autoconf
./configure
```

in my generated makefile I get

```
BINDIR=${exec_prefix}/bin
```

but when I do

```
@echo $(exec_prefix)
```

it seems that this variable is empty, so everything I would

```
make install
```

would go to /bin, which is a bit strange, why it isn't set as /usr/bin, should I issue some arguments to autoconf?

Also in this .pdf file it is written that:

```
bindir is an output variable of AC INIT which also detects includedir, srcdir, libdir, and others.
```

is is true? Because in this example of autoconf.am it is:

```
AC_INIT(helloworld, 0.0.1, dev@helloworld.org)
```

so this simple macro does all of this? If yes, how?

Comment: You have probably made a typo, or are otherwise misinterpreting your results.  There should be a line in the generated Makefile that sets exec_prefix to ${prefix},

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `AC_INIT` does all of that ;-) You can tell how it does that by looking in `/usr/share/autoconf/autoconf/general.m4` to see how `AC_INIT` and its subroutines are defined. Or, just make a `configure.ac` that is empty except for the `AC_INIT` call, and then look at the generated configure script to see what it expands to.

I think that if `exec_prefix` is unset, it defaults to `prefix`, so the binaries would still go into `/usr/local/bin`. Of course you can verify this by simply running `make install` and checking where the binaries went.

Comment: +1, but I question the wisdom of recommending someone look in general.m4!

Comment: Autotools default to a base prefix of /usr/local, not /usr, so if you don't change it then exec_prefix will be /usr/local/bin.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, I wanted to drive the point home that `AC_INIT` isn't a "simple" macro...

Comment: Thanks, it tires to install to /usr/local/bin so it is ok, i can accept that. :)